# Dynamic class instantiation

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, lambda

I have classes which are derived from a base class and would like to instantiate these classes dynamically at run time. Using the following code, I can build a class using the default constructor:

```
public abstract class Employee : IEmployeeInterface
{    
 public string Name { get; set; }

 public Employee() { }

 public Employee(string name)
 {
    Name = name;
 }    
}

public static class EmployeeBot
{
    static readonly Func<string, Func<Employee>> EmployeeBotFunction = x =>
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee>>(
    Expression.New(Type.GetType(x).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes))
    ).Compile();

    public static Employee InstantiateNewEmployee(string type)
    {
        string argumentType = string.Format("{1}.{0}", type.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace);
        return EmployeeBotFunction(argumentType).Invoke();
    }
}
```

`Worker` implements `Employee` and can be created using:

```
Employee employee = EmployeeBot.InstantiateNewEmployee("Worker");
```

Then, since `Worker` has all the same methods as `Employee`, calling them will give the results from the worker class as expected.

However, I cannot work out how to correctly implement similar code to use a constructor with arguments. For example:

```
static readonly Func<string, Type[], Func<string, Employee>> NewEmployee = (x, y) =>
Expression.Lambda<Func<string, Employee>>(
Expression.New(Type.GetType(x).GetConstructor(y))
).Compile();

public static Employee InstantiateNewEmployee(string type, string Name)
{
 Type[] construct = new Type[] { typeof(string) }; 
 string argumentType = string.Format("{1}.{0}", type.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace);
 return NewEmployee(argumentType, construct).Invoke(Name);
}
```

Calling this method throws an exception:

> EmployeesTests.InstantiateEmployeeWithName threw exception: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Method may only be called on a Type
>   for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.

How can the `NewEmployee` function be altered to accept the required parameters for the second constructor?

Comment: This is looks a little contrived and X/Yish, what are you actually trying to solve here ?

Comment: I want to be able to determine the class at runtime and perform calculations relevant to that class. For example, enumerate a list of Employees at runtime and calculate their bonus payments. Having separate classes for each type would keep the code separate and avoid using switches or many if then statements.

Comment: In your second example are you sure you're calling the right variant of the `Expression.New` maybe [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346083(v=vs.110).aspx), because I only see one argument to the New expression.

Comment: Consider having a list of PayRule classes, each derived from an interface so they all have a method called Calculate(). Each could be determined at runtime so enumerating a list of PayRule and calling Calculate() on every item would give interesting results. The problem is just how to instantiate each Employee or PayRule dynamically without using the default constructor.

Comment: Thanks @JSteward I'm not really sure how to create a new `Expression[]` and pass in my string?

Comment: Here some general info to get started, can't do anything but comment right now. [Linq Expressions Creating Objects](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this with the help of @JSteward so thank you!

Combined with a different version of `Expression.New` and fixing a stupid mistake I was able to solve this. You cannot instance an abstract class so my constructor should have been on one of the derived classes, e.g `public class Worker : Employee` and not `public abstract class Employee`.

The actual error was that the constructor parameter to the `Expression.New(Type.GetType(x).GetConstructor(y));` was `null` because it was not defined on the Worker.

The second example now becomes; (though I'm sure this can be improved!).

```
static readonly Func<string, Type[], ParameterExpression[], Func<string, Employee>> NewEmployee = (x, y, z) =>
Expression.Lambda<Func<string, Employee>>(
        Expression.New(Type.GetType(x).GetConstructor(y), z)
, z).Compile();

public static Employee InstantiateNewEmployee(string type, string Name)
{
 Type[] construct = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
 string argumentType = string.Format("{1}.{0}", type.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace);
 ParameterExpression[] arguments = new ParameterExpression[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(string)) };
 return NewEmployee(argumentType, construct, arguments).Invoke(Name);
}
```

The post from @JSteward 's comments actually generalises this requirement already: [linq-expressions-creating-objects](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/,%22linq-expressions-creating-objects%22)

I appreciate your help and also the comment from the blog.

> But good to see that I’m not the only person crazy enough to be using Expressions in this way!